# First Order Logic - Negation in embed functions

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, conjunctive-normal-form

Given the First Order Logic Sentence :

```
¬SubsetOf((Intersection(s,t),s)
```

where *Constants :* **s,t** are Sets and *Functions:* SubsetOf(.,.) , Intersection(.,.) are Sets Functions

Should the negation be moved inwards , like that :

```
SubsetOf((¬Intersection(s,t),s)
```

Or it should be left as it is ?

Comment: I presume the "Intersection" represents a set. Negating a set doesn't make sense. Instead you could translate "E is a subset of F" as "For all x, x in E implies x in F", and then try negating that.

Comment: The formula nust be read "the intersection of $s$ and $t$ is **not** a subset of $s$", i.e. $\lnot ((s \cap t) \subseteq s)$.

Comment: The *negation* sign applies to a *formula*, like: $(s \cap t) ⊆ s)$ and not to *terms* (i.e. "names") like: $s,t$ and $s \cap t$.

Answer (score 0):

Since SubsetOf(x, y) is a predicate, negation inwards is not needed. Only if x, y are associated with $\lor$ and $\land$, you should use De Morgan's Law to move NOTs inwards repeatedly.

[Wiki CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)

Answer (score 0):

Truth-functional operators like the negation can only be applied to *claims*, e.g. I can say that the claim $P$ is *not* true by saying $\neg P$.

Such operators do *not* apply to objects (terms, to be exact), e.g. I can;t take an object $a$, and then claim to say something meaningful when I say 'not $a$'.

A typical mistake beginners of logic make is to translate 'a is not b' with $a = \neg b$, and again, this is a mistake since the negation is in front of an object, not a claim. The right translation should be $\neg a = b$.

You are making a similar mistake when you say $\neg Intersection(s,t)$, since $Intersection(s,t)$ is not a claim, but a term: it is the object that results from intersecting $s$ and $t$.